# Changes in Time Range

Tags: time

I'm looking for an unambiguous wording for the "changed" term for these scenarios:

I've a time range from August 6th to August 10th.

A: I'm changing this time range to August 13th to August 17th
B: I'm changing this time range to August 7th to August 9th
C: I'm changing this time range to August 6th to August 17th

A is a completely different time tange, while B shrinks the existing one and C extends it.

I'm looking for an unambiguous wording for A and B+C combined.

**Update**:

Sample for scenario A: If time range is ___ the data should be completely removed.

Sample for scenario B+C: If time range is ___ the data should be updated.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. Can you give examples of things you didn't find suitable and reasons why wording it as in your question (where it's pretty unambiguous) is unsuitable? I think specifying dates as you've done is about as unambiguous as you're going to get.

Comment: @Pam agreed.  Are you hung up on the word 'range' for some reason?  Would 'interval' work better?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: The word 'range' doesn't necessarily mean just the duration.  The start and end points can be part of the 'range'.

Comment: I still don't understand what "A and B+C combined" means. Can you give an example sentence of that, even if it's ungrammatical? Moreover, a simple *The dates are now X to Y* applies regardless of any particular sense. So, I'm failing to understand why there's a need to distinguish between "completely different," "shrinking," and "growing." Is the specific semantic distinction required for an unstated purpose?

Comment: As I understand it you don't like the term 'changing' itself. If that's right, is there a reason you don't like it?

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm looking for two terms which unambiguously distinct between scenario A and the scenarios B and C.

Comment: @SConroy I don't want to use "changing" for both cases as they're distinct in our software case and I need a proper wording here to make both intentions clear.

Comment: I understand each word you're saying, but I still don't understand what you're trying to express. Can you provide an example sentence in which your target word is replaced with ___ ?

Comment: @JasonBassford I updated the question

Comment: What do you mean by *time range*? No times are given. Do you mean *date range*? Also, the start and end dates are changed in *all* of your scenarios, so I don't see how you see A being different from B or C. I only see two things that make A different from B or C: in A, the *duration* of the event is not changed; and in A, there are no individual *days* within the new date range that existed within the old date range (in both B and C, the old and new data ranges share at least one day in common). Is it perhaps this last difference that you are focusing on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has already been pointed out in the comments, this question is less than clear. The best interpretation of it is that the OP is trying to express, in general terms, the difference between, on one side, the changes such as A, and, on the other side, the changes such as B and C, because these different kinds of changes call for different follow-up actions. That difference appears to be that a change of the first kind results in a range (interval) that does not **overlap** the original one, while a change of the second kind results in a range that overlaps it. A clear way to reformulate the sample sentences at the end of the question could thus be:

If the new range does not overlap the original one, the data should be completely removed.

If the new range overlaps the original one, the data should be updated.

These are admittedly reformulations that do not fill the blanks with a single word, but chances are that insisting on a single word would produce something that would, in fact, be less clear.